# Add value to key, depending on if the value is in another key

Tags: python, list, dictionary, key

I have the following dictionary:

```
{'Atlanta': [['Bear', 34274], ['Deer', 13747], ['Bee', 83743]],
 'New York': [['Bear', 987], ['Dove', 2635]]}
```

A key that has a list as a value that contains lists with pairs of Animals and a number.
Now I want that if a Animal exists in of of the keys, I want it also in all other keys but with a Zero instead of the number, so the dictionary should look like this:

```
{'Atlanta': [['Bear', 34274], ['Deer', 13747], ['Bee', 83743], ['Dove', 0]], 
 'New York': [['Bear', 987], ['Dove', 2635], ['Deer', 0], ['Bee', 0]]}
```

I cannot figure out how to do this. Can someone help me?

Comment: did one of the below solutions help? If so, feel free to accept one (green tick on left), or ask further questions.

Answer (score 1):

Find all animal names first:

```
d = {'Atlanta': [['Bear', 34274], ['Deer', 13747], ['Bee', 83743]], 
     'New York': [['Bear', 987], ['Dove', 2635]]}

>>> animals = {animal for value in d.values() for animal, _ in value}
>>> animals
{'Bear', 'Bee', 'Deer', 'Dove'}
```

and pad the missing ones with zeros:

```
for key, value in d.items():
    selected_animals = {animal for animal, _ in value}
    for name in animals - selected_animals:
        d[key].append([name, 0])
```

Now:

```
>>> d
{'Atlanta': [['Bear', 34274], ['Deer', 13747], ['Bee', 83743], ['Dove', 0]],
 'New York': [['Bear', 987], ['Dove', 2635], ['Deer', 0], ['Bee', 0]]}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is similar to [@MikeMuller's perfectly fine solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49188084/9209546). But I go via `pandas`, because for your use case you may wish to perform further manipulations which are easier with a purpose-built library.

In this example, the pivot table produced *may* be all you need.

```
import pandas as pd, numpy as np
from collections import defaultdict

d = {'Atlanta': [['Bear', 34274], ['Deer', 13747], ['Bee', 83743]],
     'New York': [['Bear', 987], ['Dove', 2635]]}

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Location', 'Animal', 'Number'])

for k, v in d.items():
    for i in v:
        df.loc[len(df.index)+1] = [k, i[0], i[1]]

res = pd.pivot_table(df, index='Location', columns='Animal',
                     values='Number', aggfunc=np.sum, fill_value=0).reset_index()

# Animal  Location   Bear    Bee   Deer  Dove
# 0        Atlanta  34274  83743  13747     0
# 1       New York    987      0      0  2635

d_out = defaultdict(list)

for idx, row in res.iterrows():
    for i in row.index[1:]:
        d_out[row[0]].append([i, row[i]])

# defaultdict(list,
#             {'Atlanta': [['Bear', 34274],
#               ['Bee', 83743],
#               ['Deer', 13747],
#               ['Dove', 0]],
#              'New York': [['Bear', 987],
#               ['Bee', 0],
#               ['Deer', 0],
#               ['Dove', 2635]]})
```